# Word for "a piece of a whole"

Tags: nouns

What is a word that means "parts of a whole" and implies it can be combined with others of the same word to build something greater?

For example "blocks", "bricks", and "pieces" are examples I thought of. They are decent because they are abstract or general enough to refer to many different things that may be "pieces of a whole". I am looking for other words that are also general, and clearly communicate that they are an object alone, but can be assembled into something greater.

Comment: Good advice ermanen, thanks for taking the time to write it. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: "Part" is what you're looking for.

Comment: Please clarify what **single** answer would satisfy the question. StackExchange is for questions that have exactly one correct answer.

Comment: I'm a fan of "moiety"

Answer (score 8):

***[constituent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constituent)*** *(n)*

> one of the parts that form something

It is used as an adjective also:

> serving to form, compose, or make up a unit or whole :  *component < constituent parts >*

---

Its synonyms component and integral can be used also depending on the context.

Note: Integral is a bit tricky though. As a noun, it means the whole; but as an adjective, it has the connotation of the part of a whole. It is usually used with *part*.

> of or belonging as an essential part of the whole; necessary to completeness; constituent: *an integral part.*

---

You also asked for *"an object alone, but can be assembled into something **greater.**"*

Thus, I'm going to say ***synergistic element***. Because *[synergy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy)* is:

> the interaction of multiple elements in a system to produce an effect different from or greater than the sum of their individual effects.

Comment: Like, one of the parts that form sentences.

Answer (score 7):

Try Component or Components

As in "component parts"

Comment: Hi Jon, 'component' looks fine but it is already mentioned in the answer posted by 'ermanem'.

Comment: @Josh61- There, component was used in a definition supporting *constituent* as an answer, not offered as a answer outright.  I think Jon's answer is fine.

Answer (score 4):

I would call them [building blocks](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/building%20block) or *units*.

> a basic unit from which something is built up.

Answer (score 4):

Try 'element' :

element (plural elements)

"One of the simplest or essential parts or principles of which anything consists, or upon which the constitution or fundamental powers of anything are based."

http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/element

Answer (score 2):

"Cog", as in a cog in a machine.

Not as naturally general as "part", but still has connotations that it is an object that is part of a greater thing, and the term is often used metaphorically.

Answer (score 1):

The word **[accretion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accretion)** *an added part; addition* and can be used for organic or inorganic growth/enlargement to form a whole concept or thing

Answer (score 1):

You already have the noun “[part](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/part)”. It carries the connotations of “can be combined with other [parts] to build something greater”.

Answer (score 1):

Set members may be a term close to filling the need you described.

Answer (score 1):

How about a *fragment*?

> a small part broken off or separated from something.
>   "small fragments of pottery"

Comment: This adds to or slightly shifts the meaning, Bloodcount.